# Unable to type diaeresis using keyboard

Tags: keyboard, unicode, manjaro, input

Since migrating from Linux Mint 18.3 to the latest Manjaro stable, I have been unable to type diaereses. When I try, it immediately creates a quotation mark, instead of waiting for other input (another letter to create diaeresis or space to create quotation mark).

I could not find anything related on the internet to solve this problem, but maybe my google-fu deserted me on this one. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Set the keyboard layout to US International?

Comment: I already tried, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I switched to US international with dead keys, it did work. Don't know why I didn't try that one earlier!

Comment: one of the standard `us` layout variants (`altgr-intl`) puts the deadkeys on layer 3 rather than layer 1 (as in the `intl` and `alt-intl` variants), so you'd have to hit `AltGr+"` to activate the deadkey function.  the text descriptions on most layout configuration tools don't always make the difference clear.